# Database Project in VS2013: `Invalid object name` when trying to create a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2013

This is my first time working on a database project, and I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

I simply followed the instruction on Microsoft to create a database project as listed below:

1. Create a new database project
2. Clicked `Import` --> `Database` and successfully imported tables
3. Clicked `Add` --> `Stored Procedure...`

However I keep getting this `Invalid object name 'TABLENAME'.` message for any tables I've imported.

I've tried `Use DATABASE_NAME;` but it did not help.

Also I've read about refreshing IntelliSense but I do not get the refresh option in VS2013. Plus, it's not just the IntelliSense because I still get the same error when I manually type in the table name.

Even if I create a stored procedure directly in SSMS and then try to run it, I still get the same `Invalid object name` error.

Any help is appreciated very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't change the connection setup to use the correct database server (I was using the local one).

1. Right click the database project --> Properties
2. Click `Debug`
3. Under `Target Connection String`, click `Edit` and select the correct database server
4. Create a new stored procedure (I've tried up to STEP3 but my problem was that I was not testing on a new stored procedure after changing the connection setup)